# Android: In which file store a connection string

Tags: android

I have a connection string containing the IP of the server. Now I want to put this connection string in an external file, so that when someone clones my project, can easily change it before compiling it with the new connection string.
Then of course I have to read my connection string from this file when the app is running on the android device.
Which file is used for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it in your gradle script, like this:

```
 defaultConfig {
    resValue "string", "ip", "someIP"
 }
```

and then access like normal string resource

```
getString(R.string.ip);
```

Comment: Sorry, in which gradle file and where in the gradle file have I to put this? Should it be in defaultConfig?

Comment: in your app module gradle file

Comment: how does this work if you are deploying through google play?  how do you switch strings when promoting from alpha/beta to production?

Comment: If you have different strings for alpha/beta you can use flavors